# what should I do to found which process using the nfs folder

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

Today when I using this command to delete the nfs 4.0 folder:

```
/opt/data/project/2023/9 # rm -rf c48c542a878b4d538219a905cc864b85
rm: can't remove 'c48c542a878b4d538219a905cc864b85/.nfs0000000002cce228005af196': Resource busy
```

I have checked the folder `c48c542a878b4d538219a905cc864b85` did not contains any files, why still shows resource busy? how can I found which process using this folder? or what should I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: I would recommend you to use `lsof`